# Every keyword needs to be present

Tags: c#, regex

For example, there are several sentences:

> xx received by 2 sent from 1 
>   yy received by 3 sent from 1 
>   zz received by 1 sent from 3 
>   aa received by 4 sent from 1

How can I find all sentences contains `1` **and** `3`?

I need the result to be

> yy received by 3 sent from 1 
>   zz received by 1 sent from 3

in this case.

The closest I tried is `Regex r = new Regex (".*(3).*(1).*");` but obviously it is not the solution.

Comment: You can use `^(?=.*1).*3.*$` regex.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov damn great, it works! Also, could you please give some explanation about the logic? if so, it would be a big help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ instead of regex:

```
var strs = new string[] { "xx received by 2 sent from 1",
"yy received by 3 sent from 1",
"zz received by 1 sent from 3",
"aa received by 4 sent from 1" };
var myres = strs.Where(p => p.Contains("1") && p.Contains("3")).ToList();
```

[image]

If you prefer a Regex approach (it will be slower):

```
 ^(?=.*1)(?=.*3).*
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3D.*1)(%3F%3D.*3).*&i=xx%20received%20by%202%20sent%20from%201%20%0D%0Ayy%20received%20by%203%20sent%20from%201%20%0D%0Azz%20received%20by%201%20sent%20from%203%20%0D%0Aaa%20received%20by%204%20sent%20from%201%20&o=m) (if you want to use `IsMatch()`, you do not need `.*` at the end of the pattern).

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^(?=.*1)(?=.*3)");
var myres2 = strs.Where(p => rx.IsMatch(p)).ToList();
```

The regex matches

- `^` - Start of string and then...
- `(?=.*1)` - makes sure there is at least one `1` from the start of the string
- `(?=.*3)` - makes sure there is at least one `3` (*again!*) from the start of the string.

The `(?=...)` construction is knows as *positive look-ahead*, one of the so-called [*look-arounds*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> Lookaround actually matches characters, but then *gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match*.

So, when you have 2 look-aheads in a row, they are all "run" at the same location in the input string, and we have the logical AND that way. See more about that in [*Lookarounds Stand their Ground*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#stand_their_ground).

Comment: Great, exactly what I was trying to do. But could you please give some explanation about `?=`, does Regex ignore the order you declare? I mean, you write `1` before `3` but it knows to find also `3` before `1`? Besides why there is a need for `^`? Thanks!

Comment: :) I was writing my explanation when you added your comment. I will add more since you are interested.

Comment: Thanks! So what's the difference with `^(?=.*1).*3.*$`? This one also works (although I prefer your solution, it looks even for both `1` & `3` lol)

Comment: @MarsonMao: I think Ulugbek was following the [`For n conditions, use n-1 lookaheads`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#n-1conds) principle, but my tests on [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) prove my regex is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for a 3 followed by a 1 on the same line, or a 1 followed by a 3 with the following Regular Expression

```
^.*?((3)(?=.*?1)|(1)(?=.*?3)).*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ML-g4VDrK2UZ96w9)